# Ajax get file - where are the contents loaded?

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
async function loadFile()
{
  await $.ajax({
  url: 'folder/names.txt',
  dataType: 'text',}).done(success);
}
```

I've come across the following function. Where are the contents of names.txt saved?

Comment: `success` in this case is a function. Look at what it does